# How to feed my webcam's input to a machine I SSHed into?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, camera

I am working on a Machine Learning model that works on video data. I made this model on an AWS EC2 instance with GPU that I SSHed into. And as part of testing it, I would like to test it with live data feed from my webcam. How do I feed my webcam's input to this machine?

Both the machines run Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

USB/IP should work for you if your webcam works via this interface:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB/IP
- https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-a-usb-over-ip-server-and-client-with-debian-lenny